# What are some good examples of using enum in C

Tags: c, enums

I wrote this simple code to test enum but it doesn't feel like anything that would ever be used in the real world. I'd like to know what some good example use cases of enum would be and why it's useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    BLUE,
    GREEN,
    BROWN
} eye_color;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *eyecolor;
    int height;
    int weight;
    eye_color eyes;
} person;

void print_eye_color(person p)
{
    switch(p.eyes) {
        case BLUE :
            // I didn't know what else to say... 
            printf("%s eyes are made from diamonds\n", p.eyecolor);
            break;
        case GREEN : 
            printf("%s eyes are made from emeralds\n", p.eyecolor);
            break;
        case BROWN : 
            printf("%s eyes are made from amber\n", p.eyecolor);
        default :
            printf("What colour eyes do you have?\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    person ayla = {"Ayla", "Blue", 167, 42, BLUE};
    print_eye_color(ayla);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Search for `enum` in `/usr/include` to see some of the uses in Linux.

Comment: It's either enums or integer constants, or char strings

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and learn to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not printfing enum with %s, printfing char*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch He's not having a problem with the code, why does he need to use a debugger?

Comment: `enum` can be used to define names for numeric parameters to APIs, although when I search Unix source code I find that they usually use `#define` instead.

Comment: Enums allow for logical grouping, for example the state of a process (running, cancelled, done). Enums are safer than `#define`'d values because they are not part of the preprocessor. They also make for a better API design: `enum process_state get_process_state();` VS `int get_process_state();`.

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to write a card game, I would use an enum to represent the color of the cards, the value, and the type.

So I would have something like:

```
typedef enum {
    KING, QUEEN, ACE, JACK, TEN, NINE, EIGHT, SEVEN, SIX, FIVE, FOUR, THREE, TWO
} card_value;

typedef enum {
    SPADE, HEART, DIAMOND, CLUB
} card_type;

typedef enum {
    BLACK, RED
} card_color;
```

This is as opposed to doing:

```
const int CARD_COLOR_RED = 1;
```

or worse

```
const char* CARD_COLOR_RED = "Red";
```

---

Enums are **self-documenting** - I don't need to know what value the enum `RED` represents, I just need to know that it is `RED`.

It also makes for less time writing code (programmer efficiency) in that you are not having to think of values to assign to your constants because as it turns out, the name you gave it is the value you wanted it to have in the first place.

Enums are similar to atoms in erlang.

Answer (score 2):

Enums help avoid "magic numbers" by giving those numbers an identity and a name. You can omit the number and the compiler will generate a sequence automatically, but you can also assign values to each name yourself.

Example:

```
typedef enum {
    red = 0xff0000,
    green = 0x00ff00,
    blue = 0x0000ff,
    magenta = 0xff00ff,
    yellow = 0xffff00,
    cyan = 0x00ffff,
    white = 0xffffff,
    black = 0x000000
} colors_24bit;
```

There are many use cases for enums, but their ultimate purpose is to help you make your code clean and easy to understand.